# Radio Button Value in pdf (javascript calculation)

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a form which I am creating in Adobe Pro.

The "Grandtotal" field is determined by a variety of radio buttons selected.

My first step is to give each of the radio buttons a value.

My set of radio buttons is called "Options"  -   Radio button 1: "15"
                                                 Radio button 2: "25"

What javascript could I use to put the value of the selected radio button (either 15 or 25) into my "Grandtotal" field ?

I have tried the following:

```
var option1 = this.getField("Options");
var option2 = this.getField("Options");

var total = this.getField("Grandtotal").value;
event.value = option1 or option2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the use of Javascript in PDFs, but what I found online, it looks like you should use something like this:

```
var option1 = this.getField("Options1");  // Get first radio button
var option2 = this.getField("Options2");  // Get second radio button
var total = this.getField("Grandtotal");  // Get grand total textbox

if (option1.checked) {
    total.value = option1.value;
} else if (option2.checked) {
    total.value = option2.value;
}
```

Now, I'm not sure what you mean by `my set of radio buttons is called "Options"`, because that would mean retrieving the radio button fields might be different.

Comment: In Adobe you assign a group of radio buttons to the same name in order for only one of the radio buttons to be selected, and then you give each radio button in that group its own value.  Im still so new to this and am not quite sure myself.  I can definitely use what you provided though, thank you

Comment: @user1426583 Ahh I see. Well instead of what I have, what if you use `var options = this.getField("Options"); this.getField("GrandTotal").value = options.value;`? What does that do? I'm just wondering what `getField` does on a "set" of radio buttons...so what using `.value` on that would do.

Comment: thank you so much for your help.  I found this which seems to do this trick for now:  http://forums.adobe.com/message/4697508   thank you

Comment: @user1426583 Nice! Glad I could at least contribute!